# How do I create an Android Test Module in IntelliJ 13 for a Gradle Android project?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-testing

I have successfully create a Android project in IntelliJ 13 and I want to setup the Android Testing Framework. I used the new project wizard to create the android project using Gradle. When I go to add a new module I only have options for "Gradle: Android Module" and "Gradle: Java Library", the "Test Module" option is missing.

How do I generate an Android Test Module? I have read http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/testing-android-applications.html but I can never find any "test" option.

If an Android Test Module can not be automatically generated, then how do I configure and use the Android Testing Framework with a Gradle Android Project? Links to examples or documentation is very much appreciated.

***Details:*** IntelliJ 13.1.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So currently your directory structure should look something like this:

```
ProjectDirectory/
  res/
  src/
    main/
      java/
        your.package.name
          MyClass.java
```

All you need to do is add a src directory for `androidTest`:

```
ProjectDirectory/
  res/
  src/
    main/
      java/
        your.package.name
          MyClass.java
    androidTest/
      java/
        your.package.name
          MyClassTest.java
```

and then resync your Gradle file with your project, and it should be detected as a test directory. Then you can run the `connectedCheck` or `connectedAndroidTest` tasks (I'm unclear on the difference in the two) to run the tests.

If your directory structure differs from the above (if, for instance, you important an Eclipse-style project), you can specify the alternate src directory in your build.gradle script:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['path/to/test/src']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am somewhat surprised to see that this works because the Ant setup for this is much more complicated and involved multiple modules. I would also add that running the test in IntelliJ is very simple, just right click on the test and select "run" for android.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere that you know of?

Comment: Yup, you can find more info here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Basics-and-Configuration

Comment: thanks, all other online tutorials, even official one are outdated.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative You could try switching to [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html), Its built on top of ItelliJ. If you are creating a new project Android Studio creates the test directory automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of tries I've found the way that's definitively good:

1. Create a test folder under your package.
2. Create a class (call it `ExampleTest` would be good) extending `InstrumentationTestCase` into this folder.
3. Lets add a simple test which we know will fail:

   ```
   public class ExampleTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {
       public void test() throws Exception {
           final int expected = 1;
           final int reality = 5;
           assertEquals(expected, reality);
       }
   }
   ```

Remeber that all test methods MUST start with the “test-” prefix or Android Studio will not detect them as tests and you will get all kinds of weird errors and nothing will work.

Now that we have a test case which is doomed for failure, we must now run it.
Start by clicking “Run -> Edit Configurations.”
Now select “+ -> Android Tests” from the upper left hand corner and select “Android Tests” and name your new test configuration “test” or something equally relevant.

Select your current module and next select the “All in Package” option and navigate to your “test” folder you just created. You can also select “All in Module” and Android Studio will automatically find any test inside your whole Module! You can also get more specific and select “Class” or even “Method” option to narrow the scope of your testing down further.

Apply, close, and run this configuration! The test will run..!

Information are taken by this link:
http://rexstjohn.com/unit-testing-with-android-studio/
It's written for android studio, but it work for intelliJ 13 too! ;)
have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble with creating android projects in Intellij, so now I create projects in Eclipse and then import them into Intellij. It's annoying, but it's an easy fix and it works.

Comment: Have you tried this for a Gradle build? or only an Ant build?

Comment: Sorry my reply is a bit late. So far i have tried it only with ant, but as it seems as though eclipse is the most supported IDE for Android Dev i weighs assume it would work with gradle too.

Comment: This Question is specifically for a Gradle build because Ant and Gradle projects are setup very differently. It is my understanding that Android is moving away form both Ant and Eclipse in favor of Gradle and Android Studio (built on top of IntelliJ). IntelliJ can setup the Ant project without any issues.